# Is a cover letter required when enquiring about the potential to do a post doc in a lab when no position is advertised?

Tags: postdocs, application-cover-letter

Do I need to attach a cover letter when no position is advertised and I just want to ask about the opportunities in a potential lab? Or should I just briefly incorporate the cover letter into the email?

Comment: Are you an undergrad looking for a lab, or grad student?  A few more details would help.

Comment: I mean for seeking a postdoc.

Answer (score 1):

In my first post-doc currently - I sent a couple of solicitations out to some labs while applying to posted positions (one of which I got). Remember this - professors receive a dizzying amount of email in a given day; including a cover letter with your career goals, research interests, and a description of how those fit with the work of the lab you are seeking to join would likely go a long way in getting his/her attention. You don't want to end up in the numerous emails that go straight to the trash - show this potential employer how serious you are!